# Adding numbers using subtraction instead

Tags: python

This is subconcious coding. This is not new by any means at all!
I am only keeping the question because I can't delete it.

I've just realized that subtracting negative numbers from zero gives the same result as adding the positive versions of the numbers together.

Here's a demo (in Python):

```
def plus(x, y):
    return 0 - ((-x) - y) # which is equal to x + y
```

The question is: is this more efficient than regular adding?

Comment: I did not downvote, but this is off-topic, and what you think you have "discovered" is actually something too basic in maths we learn at primary school (no offense, though)

Comment: Some might have downvoted because this does not seem to be written to be good code. This could even be considered code obfuscation, which would be off-topic on Code Review. Our help center says *"Do I want the code to be good code?

It's OK to ask for help to optimize code to run in a resource-constrained environment. However, asking about code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar is off-topic."* https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Edited to reflect opinions

Answer (score 3):

It is not more efficient. Its more typing and does the exact same as x + y. So why bother using this?